# Where does Nautilus store its bookmarks?

Tags: nautilus

In my Ubuntu, I have added some frequented directories to the bookmarks of Nautilus, for visiting them quicker.

1. I am looking for where the dir bookmarks of Nautilus are stored, but
   to no avail:

   ```
   $ find ~ -name nautilus | less        
   ./.config/nautilus
   ./.gconf/apps/nautilus
   ./.gconf/apps/ubuntuone/nautilus
   ./.gnome2/accels/nautilus

   $ find ~ -name bookmarks | less
   ./.streamtuner/cache/bookmarks
   ./.config/zathura/bookmarks
   ./.elinks/bookmarks
   ```

   I checked the above locations, and content of the files there, but
   didn't find anything for bookmarks.
2. Is it possible to convert the dir bookmarks in Nautilus to links? It seems like dirs can't have hard links, but I prefer the links can still work after changing the dirs' name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bookmarks are stored in the file `$HOME/.gtk-bookmarks` (Ubuntu 12.04) or `$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` (Ubuntu 14.04)

In Linux you can't create hard links but only soft links (symlinks) for directories.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is it possible to convert the nautilus dir bookmarks to softlinks? (2) What can I do if I really need some "links" to frequented dirs which can still work after changing the dirs' names?

Comment: I don't have that directory. My Ubuntu is 12.04, and I have `$HOME/.config/gtk-2.0', which doesn't have `bookmarks` inside. Also see the output of my searching for `bookmarks`.

Comment: Added info for 12.04 to the answer. What do you mean by " convert the nautilus dir bookmarks to softlinks"?

Comment: Thanks. (1) how do you find `$HOME/.gtk-bookmarks`? (2) I am wondering about how to write a (bash) script to convert the contents of `$HOME/.gtk-bookmarks` to links (softlinks or hardlinks)

Comment: The bookmarks file is now in $HOME/.config/gtk-3.0